# indexOf returning -1 when it clearly shouldn't

Tags: java

```
int[] sorted = {10,67,68,28};
int[] sortedOriginal = sorted.clone();
Arrays.sort(sorted);

System.out.println(Arrays.asList(sorted).indexOf(sortedOriginal[0]));
```

In this very simple code I create an array of ints, clone it, and sort the original. After that I try to find the index given a certain value and it returns -1.

This doesn't make sense. Does anyone know why this happens and what the fix is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Arrays.asList(sorted)` returns a List having a single `int[]` element. That's the way it works on primitive arrays, so it doesn't contain `sortedOriginal[0]` (on the other hand `Arrays.asList(sorted).indexOf(sorted)` would return 0).

If you use `Integer[]` arrays, your code will work.